# An absolute package path is set for the plotly package upon installation of another package that imports it

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am writing an R package, "my_package", that has these imports on the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: jsonlite,
    tibble,
    shiny,
    ggplot2,
    plotly (>= 4.5.6.9000),
    dplyr
```

Here is my .libPaths():

```
[1] "C:/Users/some_user/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/rhome/r-3.5.1/library"
```

Here is the problem:

When I installed "my_package", the "plotly" package was located in:

```
"C:/rhome/r-3.5.1/library"
```

And everything works just fine IF the "plotly" package remains there. But If I move the "plotly" package to the other path on .libPaths():

```
"C:/Users/some_user/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
```

And then try to call a function from "my_package" that uses a function from "plotly", then this is error message:

```
ERROR: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'plotly-binding-4.8.0'; `directoryPath` = 'C:/rhome/r-3.5.1/library/plotly/htmlwidgets'
```

Here is my experimentation:

1. I tried the reverse and have the "plotly" package initially located in "C:/Users/some_user/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" and then install "my_package". And just like before it works until I move the "plotly" package into 'C:/rhome/r-3.5.1/library'. The error message is reversed:

   ERROR: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'plotly-binding-4.8.0'; `directoryPath` = 'C:/Users/some_user/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/plotly/htmlwidgets'
2. I tried the same thing with another package that "my_package" imports, which is "shiny". No issues here. It doesn't matter where "shiny" was located when "my_package" was installed. as long as "shiny" is in any one of the two paths in .libPath(), "my_package" works as expected.

So it appears that for "plotly", its path is set absolutely upon installation.

Comment: What is the actual question here? "How do I manually move packages around without breaking things?"?

Comment: @Marius Well, my manager thinks that this is a bug. He thinks that as long as "plotly" is located in any path in .libPaths(), then it should always work no matter where it was when "my_package" was installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing plotly into a different libPath (`install.packages(..., lib)`) instead of just manually moving it?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752370/in-shiny-deployment-how-to-fix-adminlte-deployment-issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when uploading to `shinyapps.io`. I was caching plots to improve load times of the plots displayed initially by default. It worked perfectly on my local machine but then it failed on `shinyapps.io`, presumably because of the reason you mentioned. The package is loaded in a different location on their servers. There is a hacky workaround. Once you generate the plot in R you can manually set the dependencies. On shinyapps.io these are the absolute paths which work. You can edit them for your use case.

```
plotObject$dependencies[[1]]$src$file = "/opt/R/3.3.2/lib/R/library/plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/typedarray"
  plotObject$dependencies[[2]]$src$file = "/opt/R/3.3.2/lib/R/library/crosstalk/lib/jquery"
  plotObject$dependencies[[3]]$src$file = "/opt/R/3.3.2/lib/R/library/crosstalk/www"
  plotObject$dependencies[[4]]$src$file = "/opt/R/3.3.2/lib/R/library/plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs"
  plotObject$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = "/opt/R/3.3.2/lib/R/library/plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs"
```

`plotObject` here is the plot generated by `plotly()`.

Comment: Dear @Sada93, please could help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752370/in-shiny-deployment-how-to-fix-adminlte-deployment-issue