# in shiny deployment, How to fix adminLTE deployment issue?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to deploy my shiny app, it works fine in localhost without any issues but when I try to deploy it, I got errors,
here is the log of my app:

```
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875187+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Server version: 1.7.8-7
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875214+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875219+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: R version: 3.6.0
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875221+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: shiny version: 1.4.0
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875221+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: httpuv version: 1.5.2
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875228+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: rmarkdown version: 2.0
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875233+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: knitr version: 1.26
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875254+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: jsonlite version: 1.6
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875265+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875269+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: htmltools version: 0.4.0
2020-01-15T05:42:16.875434+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Using pandoc at /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-01-15T05:42:17.024702+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-01-15T05:42:17.033518+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]:
2020-01-15T05:42:17.033519+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Starting R with process ID: '24'
2020-01-15T05:42:18.957820+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]:
2020-01-15T05:42:18.957822+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:38414
2020-01-15T05:42:31.586251+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in addResourcePath, with arguments: prefix = 'AdminLTE-2.0.6'; directoryPath = '/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/shinydashboard/AdminLTE'
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598820+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 118: stop
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598821+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 117: value[[3L]]
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598822+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 115: tryCatchList
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598822+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 116: tryCatchOne
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598823+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 113: addResourcePath
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598823+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 114: tryCatch
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598823+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 112: FUN
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598824+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 111: lapply
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598824+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 110: processDeps
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598824+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 109: transform
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598852+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 108: func
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598853+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 106: f
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598854+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 96: do
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598854+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 105: Reduce
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598855+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 94: origRenderFunc
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598855+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 13: runApp
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598854+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 95: hybrid_chain
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598855+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 93: output$fullPage
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598855+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 12: fn
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598856+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 7: connect$retry
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598856+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 6: eval
2020-01-15T05:42:31.598856+00:00 shinyapps[1659296]: 5: eval
```

any help, please 
thanks in advance

Comment: Very little info to go about debugging. Perhaps you can add more? Can you share the application and list packages you're using? How are you deploying?

Answer (score 0):

are you using the shinydashboardplus library? Do you have the template downloaded and located in the */home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/shinydashboard/AdminLTE* directory